# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1, product-view

i am using following code in view.phtml :

```
$sellerProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid']);

if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0) {
$rowsocial= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
} else {
 $sellersProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo();
 if ($sellersProductInfo->getSize() > 0) {
   $sellerId = $sellersProductInfo->getFirstItem()->getSellerId();
   $rowsocial = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($sellerId);
 }
}
```

but i am getting error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object` in line : `if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0)`

Comment: what is `getSelletProductInfo()` method does  above ?

Comment: $this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid']);  because it return non  object value might be empty value

Comment: put it like this  if($sellerProductInfo && is_object($sellerProductInfo) && $sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your `$sellerProductInfo` is not an object and you are calling the function `getSize()` in non-object.

I am not sure what `$this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid'])` function does, but to get rid of your error you can add this condition:

```
$sellerProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid']);

if($sellerProductInfo){ //check if this returns true
  if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0) {
  $rowsocial= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
  } else {
   $sellersProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo();
   if ($sellersProductInfo->getSize() > 0) {
     $sellerId = $sellersProductInfo->getFirstItem()->getSellerId();
     $rowsocial = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($sellerId);
   }
  }
}
```

**Remember**

Your above script will never get called if `$this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid'])` doesn't return anything.

Comment: as a note: he is redeclaring `$sellersProductInfo` in the `else` statement, with your code he will never get to that part if it is not an object